# Codeigniter Email cc and bcc not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using Email library of codeigniter. This code is properly sending mail to `$to` variable.but not to `$cc` and `$bcc`. Please help me if anybody could!

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($from);
$this->email->bcc($bcc);
$this->email->cc($cc);
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($content);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  You're either using version 2 or version 3 of CodeIgniter, not both.  Edited.

Comment: `$this->email->cc()` and `$this->email->bcc()` work for me.  You've not shown us enough code to solve this.  Maybe there is something wrong with your `$cc` and `$bcc` variables?

Comment: @sumandeep-kaur, did you ever solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Youre wrong the code, use an array on BCC.

```
$this->email->bcc(array($this->input->post('bcc_email')));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this library:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

then use this code, its working at my side:

```
$this->email->from('your@example.com', $this->input->post('fullname'));
$this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
$this->email->cc($this->input->post('cc_email'));
$this->email->bcc($this->input->post('bcc_email'));
$this->email->subject('Registeration Notification');
$this->email->message('You have registered successfully.\nYour username is :'.$this->input->post('email'));

$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Exactly how is this any different than what the OP has already tried?